# Add value from Sharedpreferences in variable (stateful widget)

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I saved the data using SharedPreferences, when my app is starting i try check type of user "client" or "company" after that wil be shown screen.

```
Future<void> setTypeClient() async {
    final _storage = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final storage = await _storage;
    storage.setString('type_user_db', 'client');
  }
```

My app is starting

I have variable

var typeUser = ' ' ;  and use it when I determine which screen to display

Аfter I get the data from SharedPreferences, I need to put value in this variable

But i have an error, cause variable remains empty

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import '../views/home_view.dart';

import '../views/auth/client_auth_view.dart';
import '../views/auth/company_auth_view.dart';
import '../views/auth/company_reg_view.dart';

import '../views/client/client_view.dart';
import '../views/company/company_view.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MyAppBody();
  }
}

class MyAppBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAppBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyAppBody> createState() => _MyAppBodyState();
}

class _MyAppBodyState extends State<MyAppBody> {
  
  Future<void> getTypeUser() async {
    final storage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final type = storage.getString('type_user_db');
    setState(() {
      typeUser = type!;
    });
  }

  var typeUser = '';

  Map<String, Widget> screenByUser = {
    'client': const ClientView(),
    'company': const CompanyView(),
  };

  bool isLogOut = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      getTypeUser();
      setState(() {
        isLogOut = false;
      });
      super.initState();
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Well Plus',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routes: {
        '/main': (context) => const HomeView(),
        '/auth_client': (context) => const AuthClientView(),
        '/auth_company': (context) => const AuthCompanyView(),
        '/reg_company': (context) => const RegCompanyView(),
        '/client': (context) => const ClientView(),
        '/company': (context) => const CompanyView(),
      },
      home: isLogOut ? const HomeView() : screenByUser[typeUser],
    );
  }
}
```

update

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import '../views/home_view.dart';

import '../views/auth/client_auth_view.dart';
import '../views/auth/company_auth_view.dart';
import '../views/auth/company_reg_view.dart';

import '../views/client/client_view.dart';
import '../views/company/company_view.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MyAppBody();
  }
}

class MyAppBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAppBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyAppBody> createState() => _MyAppBodyState();
}

class _MyAppBodyState extends State<MyAppBody> {
  
  Future<void> getTypeUser() async {
    final storage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final type = storage.getString('type_user_db');
    setState(() {
      typeUser = type!;
    });
  }

  var typeUser = '';

  Map<String, Widget> screenByUser = {
    'client': const ClientView(),
    'company': const CompanyView(),
  };

  bool get isLogOut => typeUser.isEmpty;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null) {
      getTypeUser();
      setState(() {
        isLogOut = false;
      });
      super.initState();
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Well Plus',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routes: {
        '/main': (context) => const HomeView(),
        '/auth_client': (context) => const AuthClientView(),
        '/auth_company': (context) => const AuthCompanyView(),
        '/reg_company': (context) => const RegCompanyView(),
        '/client': (context) => const ClientView(),
        '/company': (context) => const CompanyView(),
      },
      home: isLogOut ? const HomeView() : screenByUser[typeUser],
    );
  }
}
```

error in

```
 setState(() {
        isLogOut = false;
      });
```

error screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G6wq.jpg)

Comment: Where did you call `setTypeClient` method?

Comment: this method is called initially when the user is registered as a client, where the value is added to SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue we have to clarify synchronous and asynchronous operations.

Initialating you widget with `initState` and next `build` method called one by one in **synchronous** way but `getUser` is **asynchronous**.

This is meant that you specify `isLogOut` before you setting the `typeUser`.
Instead of manually setting the `isLogOut` property just to change it to `getter`

```
bool get isLogOut => typeUser.isEmpty;
```

And you can guarantee the property will be correct all the time when you requests it.

Enjoy coding

Comment: the value of bool changes, the screen opens, it happens faster than getType, so there is an error, right? I assumed it, but I don't understand how to fix it

Comment: i try to use your decision, add   bool get isLogOut , but in setState have error, can you show full code?  thanks, i`m add update

Comment: Could you provide error message?

Comment: added screenshot   https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G6wq.jpg

Comment: Remove `setState(() {  isLogOut = false;  });` because this not required anymore

Comment: sorry, it`s were my mistake in the code)  i removed it in the first place after your advice, but i made a typo in the code in another place. Thank you, so much!